# Custom Syntax Checker For an online editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, syntax-error

I am making a new programming language. Is there any project or bootstrap that I can use for syntax checking, for showing syntax errors? A project have to be built using javascript, because I need to build a syntax checker for online editor?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you explain your question in more details and possibly post here the code [you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and isn't working *(if any)*?

Comment: Its not about code. I am making an online editor for my new programming language. So, I am trying to write a program that looks for syntax error, and underlines that word or part of the sentence if it finds one, as it does in netbeans, and eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You might check out PEGjs at http://pegjs.org/ which allows you to create a parser from a grammar definition.

Comment: You just solved my problem. I wasn't able to think of phrase a simple enough sentence to get meaningful results. "Grammar" and "Parser" together solved my problem. Performed a search for "Parser Generator in "example programming language" and voila